# Check if the point lies within the 3d volume

Tags: vector-spaces, analytic-geometry

what is the condition to check if any point(x,y,z) lies within any 3d shape (cuboid, tetrahedrons etc). Is there any generic condition that I can use to compute it for any shape.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a point in space and one 3d geometry say cuboid now I want to find whether that lie lies within the cuboid or outside the cuboid

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed : If the shape is convex and built by intersecting finitely many half-spaces, you can check that the point in question lies in all those half-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

you can put x0,y0,z0 into function f(x,y,z) so that you get the plane or 'slice'
you can determine whether the point lies in the closed curve of the 3d shape in this 2d plane
if all 3 satisfies, then it's in the 3d shape

for example, you want to find whether (0,0,0) is in the shape x^2+y^2+z^2=1
you first substitute x = 0 in getting the yOz plane where y^2+z^2 =1 you find (0,0) is in this curve. using the same method, you will find its also in the curve in xOz, xOy plane, so its in the 3d shape

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty of checking if a point lies inside a given set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is related to how the set $S$ is defined. If $S$ is defined using a very simple condition, i.e. $S = \{(x,y,z) \mid x > 0\}$, then checking membership is very easy. If $S$ is defined using complicated integrals or limits, it might be very hard to ascertain if a point lies in $S$.

For the shapes you mentioned above, there is a fairly easy algorithm for checking membership. Such polyhedra are (by definition) the intersection of finitely many half-spaces (see picture below). A half-space is a subset of the form $ax + by + cz + d \geq 0$, and is one side of a hyperplane. To check that $(x,y,z)$ is inside a polyhedra, you can check that $(x,y,z)$ satisfies all of the hyperplanes defining the polyhedron. Each such calculation is very simple, and presuming that there aren't too many, this algorithm will be fast.

This isn't the only way to check set membership in *computational geometry*, but it is a fairly simple one.

[image]